# Repurpose [tag:shortcut] into [tag:app-shortcut]

Tags: discussion, tags

[keyboard-shortcut](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-shortcut) already exists and [shortcut](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shortcut) is collecting all sorts of cruft. I would propose that the latter becomes about app shortcuts in specific so we can remove the keyboard duplicates. If this rename happens, we should consider merging [.desktop-files](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.desktop-files) too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[shortcut](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shortcut) seems to be mostly synonymous with [keyboard-shortcut](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-shortcut)

[.desktop-files](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.desktop-files) has also been merged to [app-shortcuts](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/app-shortcuts)

Comment: Also [tag:keyboard-shortcut] should be merged into [tag:keyboard-shortcuts] (or vice versa, as you prefer)